# ¿Cómo puedo solucionar un CHAR autoincrementable...?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, sql-server-2019

Estuve intentando que mi llave primaria incremente cada vez que haga un registro, aquí presento mi tabla, en la cual estaba haciendo pruebas:

```
CREATE TABLE STRING
(
ID CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY
)
```

Lo realicé en un **Stored Procedure**:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [SP PK Insertion]
(
    @ID CHAR(5) OUTPUT
)

AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM STRING)
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @Number INT = 1
            SET @ID = CONCAT(CAST('E' AS CHAR(1)), CAST('M' AS CHAR(1)), CAST(@Number AS CHAR(3)))
            INSERT INTO STRING (ID)
            SELECT @ID

            SELECT 'First successful insertion PK'
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM STRING)
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @Iterate INT = 1

                DECLARE @Kidnapper INT = (SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(MAX(ID),3,3) AS INT) FROM STRING)

                SET @Kidnapper = @Kidnapper + @Iterate

                SET @ID = CONCAT(CAST('E' AS CHAR(1)), CAST('M' AS CHAR(1)), CAST(@Kidnapper AS CHAR(3)))

                INSERT INTO STRING (ID)
                SELECT @ID

                SELECT 'Last succesful insertion PK'
            END
        END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT  ERROR_LINE()        AS  [ERROR LINE],
                ERROR_MESSAGE()     AS  [ERROR MESSAGE],
                ERROR_NUMBER()      AS  [ERROR NUMBER],
                ERROR_PROCEDURE()   AS  [ERROR PROCEDURE],
                ERROR_SEVERITY()    AS  [ERROR SEVERITY],
                ERROR_STATE()       AS  [ERROR STATE]
    END CATCH
END
```

El problema me trae el **Substring()**, porque al llegar a más de diez registros me da un error, diciendo de que la llave primaria está duplicada. Quisiera saber si hay un problema con mi lógica en el código o es cosa del *substring()*.

Comment: Sí, es eso, vas a llegar a 10, haces substring 3,3 y eso da el 1, le sumas 1, queda 2, ese ya existe, pum. Haz el substring hasta el final de la cadena. Usa el valor de la longitud total de la cadena, creo que con `LEN`

Comment: Todas las lineas van a llevar EM al inicio? O insertarás valores con otros sufijos que tengan distinta numeración? Estás tratando de inventar el hilo negro cuando ya hay soluciones que resuelven este problema.

Comment: Gracias @Afabravo, andaba viendo LEN también, pero igual toma como valor máximo 'EM9', y pues eso me traería problemas supongo. Solo quería que incremente a pesar de que aumente dos dígitos, porque el 'EM10' no lo reconoce como un **10**, ya que en las filas aparece antes que el 'EM2' y no después que el 'EM9'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para no variar la linea que has utilizado para crear el procedure, hay dos cositas susceptibles de cambiar

Si no quieres tener problemas de concurrencia, y que dos variables @id y/o dos registros en la tabla `string` tengan el mismo valor, es necesario establecer el procedure como un nivel de bloqueo que impida duplicados.

La segunda, para utilizar los caracteres de la derecha (substring), puedes utilizar la longitud de la cadena menos los caracteres letra.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS STRING; 
CREATE TABLE STRING
(
ID CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY
)
```

Ahora el procedure.

```
CREATE or alter PROCEDURE [SP PK Insertion]
(
    @ID CHAR(5) OUTPUT
)

AS
BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
    BEGIN TRY
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM STRING)
        BEGIN
            DECLARE @Number INT = 1
            SET @ID = CONCAT(CAST('E' AS CHAR(1)), CAST('M' AS CHAR(1)), CAST(@Number AS CHAR(3)))
            INSERT INTO STRING (ID)
            SELECT @ID

            SELECT 'First successful insertion PK'
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM STRING)
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @Iterate INT = 1

                DECLARE @Kidnapper INT = (SELECT MAX(IDNUM) FROM (SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(MAX(ID),3,(LEN(ID)-2)) AS INT)AS IDNUM ,ID 
FROM STRING
GROUP BY ID ) Data
)

                SET @Kidnapper = @Kidnapper + @Iterate

                SET @ID = CONCAT(CAST('E' AS CHAR(1)), CAST('M' AS CHAR(1)), CAST(@Kidnapper AS CHAR(3)))

                INSERT INTO STRING (ID)
                SELECT @ID

                SELECT 'Last succesful insertion PK'
            END
        END
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT  ERROR_LINE()        AS  [ERROR LINE],
                ERROR_MESSAGE()     AS  [ERROR MESSAGE],
                ERROR_NUMBER()      AS  [ERROR NUMBER],
                ERROR_PROCEDURE()   AS  [ERROR PROCEDURE],
                ERROR_SEVERITY()    AS  [ERROR SEVERITY],
                ERROR_STATE()       AS  [ERROR STATE]
    END CATCH
END
```

Con el procedure creado. Ejecuto unas inserciones seguidas.

```
Declare @ID char(5)
exec [SP PK Insertion] @ID
exec [SP PK Insertion] @ID
exec [SP PK Insertion] @ID
exec [SP PK Insertion] @ID
exec [SP PK Insertion] @ID
exec [SP PK Insertion] @ID
exec [SP PK Insertion] @ID
exec [SP PK Insertion] @ID
exec [SP PK Insertion] @ID
exec [SP PK Insertion] @ID
exec [SP PK Insertion] @ID
exec [SP PK Insertion] @ID

Select * from string
```

[image: Res1]

[image: res2]

Comment: Desgraciadamente, la opción de hacerlo serializable no funcionaría en este caso, porque los SELECTs no generarían un bloqueo de transacciones.

Comment: Gracias @Javifer2 por el aporte y explicación; me ayudó , aunque el valor máximo igual vendría a ser el 'EM9'. Creo que una solución simple podría ser reemplazar el valor de la variable **@Number** a 100; ya que me consideraría más registros y tomaría como valor máximo la última inserción que haga.

Comment: ¿Porque dices eso?. No lo entiendo. El valor máximo será EM999. He modificado la respuesta para que veas, que sigue creciendo por encima del EM9

Comment: @Javifer2, me refería a que cuando se hace una consulta utilizando **MAX()** el valor máximo sería EM9 y no los valores después de este (EM10, EM11...).

Comment: Eso no es culpa de max sino de la forma en la que lo consultas o de la forma en la que has decidido hacer esta tabla. Pero `select Concat('EM',max(CAST((replace(id,'EM','')) AS INT))) from string` te devolverá el max para un int. EM12

Comment: Gracias, no sabía lo del **replace()** 